# How to format data copied from the Web and pasted into an Excel sheet without altering the string itself?

Tags: vba, excel

Let us say I need to copy a list of names from a webpage. Since I don't want to retain the formatting that is there in the webpage, I currently use Paste Special→"Match Destination format". This is simple and clean.

But Excel also removes any extra spaces present within the string.
e.g. ABC  DEF will become ABC DEF.
This is also true for leading and trailing spaces. I believe this is the TRIM function at work which is part of the default settings.

What can I do to apply new formatting without applying the TRIM function? (Other than pasting with source formatting and changing the format manually?)

I think the question can be extended to other parts of the default settings. e.g. the default number formatting in Excel may not be what you want. I looked at the settings under Excel→Options but could not find the settings that specified number/text formatting.

Comment: What code have you tried?  You can edit your question to add your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set that column formatting as Text (Manually) and performing Paste Special Values will consider the value as Text without changing anything in the pasted data.